# update onClickListener android

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have a button with an `onClickListener`. 
I need the `onClickListener` to change what it does (like update) 
something like this:

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                    doThis()
                                    }


updateTo.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                    doThat()
                                    }
```

How to make the `onClickListener` update? 
Thank you!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Do what? Your question makes no sense at all.

Comment: how to make the onClickListener update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i have correctly understand your question i think you should use the flowing code :

```
boolean isClicked = false;
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                               if(isClicked == true){
                                doThis();
                                isClicked = false;
                                }else 
                                 {doThat();
                                isClicked = true;}
```

Comment: tnx, but I edited it and I hope you can understand now